# how to avoid installing packages again when creating a new project in R

Tags: r, package, project

I am new to creating projects in R.

every time I create a project in a new directory, do I need to install packages I need again and again? is there a way that helps R remember it already has them installed?

Comment: No you don't have to install them again, and again, (unless you're using `{renv}`, which I assume you are not)

Comment: in fact I am using Renv. and R does not recognize any package. so what is the best way not to have to install them again.

Comment: The whole point of using renv for projects is that each project gets its own set of packages so that all the version numbers are fixed and isolated within a project so updating a package in one project won't introduce breaking changes into any other project. If that's not what you want, then you might reconsider using `renv` because it doesn't sound like that's what you want.

Comment: Yes, please consult the documentation for `renv`, like [introduction ..](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html)

Comment: Installing the new packages shouldn't be the limiting factor when you're starting a project. Plus, renv can do some fancy global caching. That means that if you have a package installed globally, it will be accessible to all your subprojects.

Comment: While the above comments are sufficient enough, you might also read the short blog entry here re. this subject.  https://statsandr.com/blog/an-efficient-way-to-install-and-load-r-packages/#pacman-package